# Stored gesture in Android?

Tags: android, store, gesture

I have one screen where the user creates a gesture, then the user presses Next and on the Next screen it asks the user to confirm that gesture. Basically I want the gesture stored as a password. The gesture creation works fine, I have the following lines of code which store the gesture in the device's memory:

```
GestureLibrary store = GestureLibraries.fromRawResource(this, R.raw.gestures);;
store.addGesture("Gesture Password", mGesture);
store.save();
setResult(RESULT_OK);
```

I'm still messing around with how to recognize the gesture but for now I'm just trying to figure out how to compare against this stored gesture in memory. I have the following:

```
public void onGesturePerformed(GestureOverlayView overlay, Gesture gesture) {
    ArrayList<Prediction> predictions = gestureLib.recognize(gesture);
    for (Prediction prediction : predictions) {
        if (prediction.score > 1.0) {
            Toast.makeText(this, prediction.name, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}
```

Where:

```
private GestureLibrary gestureLib = GestureLibraries.fromRawResource(this, R.raw.gestures);
```

As I understand, on the first screen I create the gesture, it's stored in raw.gestures, then I try accessing it again in the confirm screen and if the confirm gesture is similar enough, the toast should return "Gesture Password". But this doesn't work for some reason, what am I missing? Am I storing and retrieving the gesture incorrectly?